# How to populate a table with the results of a query?

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables table A , table B and table C. I need to populate C with the combination of A and B.

How can i populate table C with the results of the query below?

```
UPDATE dbo.C

SELECT TOP (200000) dbo.A.Id, dbo.B.Id   
  FROM [testDB].[dbo].A
  CROSS JOIN [testDB].[dbo].B
```

Comment: What do you mean by Populate (Insert/Update) ?

Comment: Lookup the syntax for INSERT SELECT.

Comment: it is an empty table insert.

Comment: If the table does not exist yet   Select * into SomeNewTable  From ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO . .SELECT` if table already exists  :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.c(aID, bID) -- Qualify correct column names 
     SELECT TOP (200000) dbo.A.Id, dbo.B.Id   
     FROM [testDB].[dbo].A CROSS JOIN 
          [testDB].[dbo].B
    ORDER BY ???; -- Use ordering column to specify the sequence
```

If `table C` doesn't exists then use `INTO`  :

```
SELECT TOP (200000) dbo.A.Id, dbo.B.Id INTO [testDB].[dbo].C
FROM [testDB].[dbo].A CROSS JOIN 
     [testDB].[dbo].B
ORDER BY ???; -- Use ordering column to specify the sequence
```